# Are there any difference in empty parentheses (“T()”) and empty braces (“T{}”) when used as initializers?

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer, list-initialization, value-initialization

Generally speaking, parentheses and braces are very different. For minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 2>{42, 42}; // OK
    std::array<int, 2>(42, 42); // ill-formed

    std::vector<int>{42, 42}; // two elements
    std::vector<int>(42, 42); // 42 elements
}
```

However, since empty braces use value-initialization instead of `std::initializer_list` constructors, is there any different between empty parentheses and empty braces when used as initializers?

More formally, given a type `T`, is it possible that `T()` and `T{}` are different?  (Either may be ill-formed.)

(This question and answer was originally created for [C++20 standard compatible vector](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/228942) on Code Review Stack Exchange. It is intended that the answer covers all possible cases.  Please inform me if I missed any.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(The links in this answer point to [N4659](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/), the C++17 final draft.  However, at the time of this writing, the situation is exactly the same for C++20.)

Yes, it's possible.  There are two cases:

### Case 1

**`T` is a non-union aggregate for which zero-initialization, followed by default-initialization if the aggregate has a non-trivial constructor, differs from copy-initialization from `{}`.**

We can use `std::in_place_t` to construct our example, because it has an explicit default constructor.  Minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <utility>

struct A {
    std::in_place_t x;
};

int main()
{
    A(); // well-formed
    A{}; // ill-formed
}
```

([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ThOuzvRkBANqiJjh))

#### Case 1, variant

**`T` is a union aggregate for whose first element default-initialization differs from copy-initialization from `{}`.**

We can change `struct` to `union` in Case 1 to form a minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <utility>

union A {
    std::in_place_t x;
};

int main()
{
    A(); // well-formed
    A{}; // ill-formed
}
```

([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OclLZ72zhqsZdF2c))

### Case 2

**`T` is of the form `const U&` or `U&&` where `U` can be list-initialized from `{}`.**

Minimal reproducible example:

```
int main()
{
    using R = const int&;
    R{}; // well-formed
    R(); // ill-formed
}
```

([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xQT3rcIOQNp3wG8K))

## Detailed explanation

### `T()`

Per [[dcl.init]/17](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#17):

> The semantics of initializers are as follows. The *destination type*
>   is the type of the object or reference being initialized and the
>   *source type* is the type of the initializer expression. If the initializer is not a single (possibly parenthesized) expression, the
>   source type is not defined.
>
> - If the initializer is a (non-parenthesized) *braced-init-list* or is `=` *braced-init-list*, the object or reference is list-initialized.
> - If the destination type is a reference type, see [dcl.init.ref].
> - If the destination type is an array of characters, an array of `char16_­t`, an array of `char32_­t`, or an array of `wchar_­t`, and
>     the initializer is a string literal, see [dcl.init.string].
> - **If the initializer is `()`, the object is value-initialized.**
> - [...]

We can conclude that `T()` always value-initializes the object.

### `T{}`

Per [[dcl.init]/17](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#17):

> The semantics of initializers are as follows. The *destination type*
>   is the type of the object or reference being initialized and the
>   *source type* is the type of the initializer expression. If the initializer is not a single (possibly parenthesized) expression, the
>   source type is not defined.
>
> - **If the initializer is a (non-parenthesized) *braced-init-list* or is `=` *braced-init-list*, the object or reference is
>     list-initialized.**
> - [...]

That's enough for us to conclude that `T{}` always list-initializes the object.

Now let's go through [[dcl.init.list]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.list#3).  I have **highlight**ed the possible cases.  The other cases are not possible because they require the initializer list to be non-empty.

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type `T` is defined
>   as follows:
>
> - (3.1) If `T` is an aggregate class and the initializer list has a single element of type *cv* `U`, where `U` is `T` or a class derived from
>     `T`, the object is initialized from that element (by
>     copy-initialization for copy-list-initialization, or by
>     direct-initialization for direct-list-initialization).
> - (3.2) Otherwise, if `T` is a character array and the initializer list has a
>     single element that is an appropriately-typed string literal
>     ([dcl.init.string]), initialization is performed as described in that
>     section.
> - (3.3) **Otherwise, if `T` is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is
>     performed.**
> - (3.4) **Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements and `T` is a class type with a default constructor, the object is
>     value-initialized.**
> - (3.5) Otherwise, if `T` is a specialization of
>     `std​::​initializer_­list<E>`, the object is constructed as described
>     below.
> - (3.6) Otherwise, if `T` is a class type, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated and the best
>     one is chosen through overload resolution ([over.match],
>     [over.match.list]). If a narrowing conversion (see below) is required
>     to convert any of the arguments, the program is ill-formed.
> - (3.7) Otherwise, if `T` is an enumeration with a fixed underlying type
>     ([dcl.enum]), the *initializer-list* has a single element `v`, and the
>     initialization is direct-list-initialization, the object is
>     initialized with the value `T(v)` ([expr.type.conv]); if a narrowing
>     conversion is required to convert `v` to the underlying type of `T`,
>     the program is ill-formed.
> - (3.8) Otherwise, if the initializer list has a single element of type `E`
>     and either `T` is not a reference type or its referenced type is
>     reference-related to `E`, the object or reference is initialized from
>     that element (by copy-initialization for copy-list-initialization, or
>     by direct-initialization for direct-list-initialization); if a
>     narrowing conversion (see below) is required to convert the element to
>     `T`, the program is ill-formed.
> - (3.9) **Otherwise, if `T` is a reference type, a prvalue of the type referenced by `T` is generated. The prvalue initializes its result
>     object by copy-list-initialization or direct-list-initialization,
>     depending on the kind of initialization for the reference. The prvalue
>     is then used to direct-initialize the reference.**
> - (3.10) **Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements, the object is value-initialized.**
> - (3.11) Otherwise, the program is ill-formed.

(Note: (3.6) is not possible in this case, for the following reason: (3.4) covers the case where a default constructor is present.  In order for (3.6) to be considered, a non-default constructor has to be called, which is not possible with an empty initializer list.  (3.11) is not possible because (3.10) covers all cases.)

Now let's analyze the cases:

#### (3.3)

For an aggregate, value-initialization first performs zero-initialization and then, if the element has a non-trivial default constructor, default-initialization, on the aggregate, per [[dcl.init]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#8):

> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> - [...]
> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type without a user-provided or deleted default constructor, then **the object is
>     zero-initialized and the semantic constraints for
>     default-initialization are checked, and if T has a non-trivial default
>     constructor, the object is default-initialized**;
> - [...]

**Non-union aggregates**

When copy-initializing a non-union aggregate from `{}`, elements that are not explicitly initialized with a default member initializer are copy-initialized from `{}` per [[dcl.init.aggr]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.aggr#8):

> If there are fewer *initializer-clauses* in the list than there are
>   elements in a non-union aggregate, then each element not explicitly
>   initialized is initialized as follows:
>
> - If the element has a default member initializer ([class.mem]), the element is initialized from that initializer.
> - **Otherwise, if the element is not a reference, the element is copy-initialized from an empty initializer list ([dcl.init.list]).**
> - **Otherwise, the program is ill-formed.**
>
> [...]

See Case 1.

**Union aggregates**

If the aggregate is a union, and no member has a default member initializer, then copying-initializing the aggregate from `{}` copy-initializes the *first* element from `{}`: [[dcl.init.aggr]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.aggr#8):

> [...]
>
> If the aggregate is a union and the initializer list is empty, then
>
> - if any variant member has a default member initializer, that member is initialized from its default member initializer;
> - **otherwise, the first member of the union (if any) is copy-initialized from an empty initializer list.**

See Case 1, variant.

#### (3.4)

Value-initialized, so no difference.

#### (3.9)

`T()` isn't allowed if `T` is a reference per [[dcl.init]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#9):

> A program that calls for default-initialization or
>   value-initialization of an entity of reference type is ill-formed.

See Case 2.

#### (3.10)

Similarly, value-initialized.  No difference.

Answer (score 1):

> is there any different between empty parentheses and empty braces when used as initializers

There are cases where empty parentheses cannot be used as initialiser because it would be syntactically ambiguous with a function declaration:

```
T t(); // function declaration; not initialisation
T t{}; // value initialisation
```

> More formally, given a type T, is it possible that T() and T{} are different?

The ambiguity described above has a case where `T()` is parsed as pointer to function, known as the Most Vexing Parse:

```
U t(T()); // function declaration; not initialisation
U t(T{}); // value initialisation, and direct initialisation
```

Comment: OK, you are absolutely right ...  I should have stressed that `T()` is intended to be an expression, but since you have written this answer, it probably makes the question more complete anyway.

Comment: @L.F. The point is that there are cases where `T()` cannot be used as an expression.

Comment: The original context is `const Allocator& alloc = Allocator()` vs `const Allocator& alloc = Allocator{}`, but you are right anyway ...